# Error when authenticating with Symfony Login Form Authenticator

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

My authentication system is completly working (I followed the documentation tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html).

But I have a problem : when a malicious user disable the required password field and try to login, I get an error 500 "Warning: empty password"

The authentication system does not work in one case :

When the user name matches the user name stored in the database but the password is empty and I try to login, then the 500 Twig error appears.

Symfony tell me the error come from : `UserPasswordEncoder->isPasswordValid(object(User), '') in src/Security/LoginFormAuthenticator.php (line 79)`

and this corresponds to this code :

```php
public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)    
{
    return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
}
```

I expect the user is redirected to login page if fields like password are missing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I retested my authentication system, everything works but it does not work only in one case:

When the user name matches the user name stored in the database but the password is empty and I try to login, then the 500 Twig error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

```php
public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)    
{
    if (empty($credentials['password'] {
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid password.');
    }

    return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
}
```